# How to search for a text string in a list of files in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, search

I need to find certain files at a SMB share containing a specific text string.

How it could be done with the search function in Windows 10?

I would not prefer the idea of indexing the files as there are a lot of them.

Example:

Search \SHARE\ for *.xml containing "Keyword"

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /m "Keyword" \SHARE\*.xml
```

Keep the quotes. If you want multiple words in the same document, separate them with a space inside the quotes. You would do this from the command prompt. Most likely you would put \\SHARE\C$\Users\Admin\Documents\*.xml or something like that.

If the share requires a username and password, make sure you open it in Explorer first and enter that info.

Comment: /s for sub folders
/I if you do not want it to be CaSe SenSitivE